# jQuery if not in function submit doesn't work anymore

Tags: jquery, validation

I working on form simple validation in my project. I check all the fields with validate="true" and check a set of radio buttons with one extra function.

First you see the function for the text fields with validate="true", then the function wz_radio_shipping for the radio buttons and then I check both functions and return true of false for the form submit.

In the function wz_radio_shipping I use a ! in the if statement. By doing this de radio buttons getting checked successfully if they are empty but my form can't submit anymore. If I remove the ! the radio button check don't work anymore but my form now can submit.

I have tried to change the ! to == "" but that doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this?

```
$(wz_form).submit(function() {

    function wz_validation() {
        var value=false;
        var txtboxes=$('input[validate="true"]');
        for(var i=0;i<txtboxes.length;i++) {

            if($(txtboxes[i]).val()=="") {
                $(txtboxes[i]).addClass('red_border');
                value=false;
            }
            else{
                $(txtboxes[i]).removeClass('red_border');
                value=true;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }


    function wz_radio_shipping() {
        if($("#shipping_form")) {
            if(!$('input[name=wz_shipping]:checked', '#shipping_form').val()) {
                $("#checkout_shipping").addClass('red_border');
                return false;   
            }
            else{
                $("#checkout_shipping").removeClass('red_border');
                return true;    
            }
        }
    }

    if(wz_validation() & wz_radio_shipping()) {
        return true;    
    }
    else{
        return false;   
    }

});
```

Comment: You have some major logic flaws in you `wz_validation` function.

Comment: Okay, but this function works fine. Added wz_radio_shipping later and this gave the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

```
if(wz_validation() & wz_radio_shipping()) { // <-- notice single "&"
```

it should be:

```
if(wz_validation() && wz_radio_shipping()) { // <-- now is double "&"
```

Try this optimised solution:

```
$(function() {
    function wz_validation() {
        var ok = true;

        $('input[validate="true"]').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == '') {
                ok = false;
                $(this).addClass('red_border');
            }
            else $(this).removeClass('red_border');
        });

        return ok;
    }

    function wz_radio_shipping() {
        var form = $("#shipping_form");
        if(form.length) {
            if(form.find('input[name=wz_shipping]:checked').length == 0) {
                $("#checkout_shipping").addClass('red_border');
                return false;   
            }
            else{
                $("#checkout_shipping").removeClass('red_border');
                return true;    
            }
        }
    }

    $(wz_form).submit(function() {
        return wz_validation() && wz_radio_shipping();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit! Only the wz_radio_shipping function doesn't work.

Comment: And I have one extra function called wz_val_select(), added this in the last submit function and also doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Try restoring your original functions with only the correction in the "&&" logic operator.

Comment: Strange.. with && my functions does not work and with & they work??

Comment: You script works if I use single "&", it adds the classes but it always submits. And if I use double "&&" only the first function works and it doesn't submit when you don't fill in the fields..

Comment: The problem is in returning (or checking) the 3 functions. I have tested by returning each function alone and all the functions are working great but if I use them all they doesn't work.

Comment: What do the single functions return?